# How can I display a pdf in a Google.Protobuf.ByteString in a new browser window or tab in a server side Blazor App?

Tags: c#, pdf, blazor, protobuff.net

So this works in displaying the file size of a pdf assembled from a .Net gRPC service, but I really would like to display the PDF in a new browser tab or window without storing it down as a file first.
Note: I'm trying to avoid using JavaScript.

```
public void DisplayPDF(Google.Protobuf.ByteString pdf){  

    //Do real Stuff here instead
    helloString = new MarkupString("PDF File size = " + pdf.Length.ToString() + " bytes");
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```